# What is best practices for upgrading for Rails 3?

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, rvm

Currently running Rails 3.07, Ruby 1.92, RVM and PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 11.04. Everything works great.

Does upgrading Ubuntu (to 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot) cause any problems in Ruby on Rails? Does upgrading Ubuntu cause problems in general? When is the "best" time to update Ubuntu?

Also, is it possible to rollback an Ubuntu upgrade?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if your current system working perfectly, what is the point of upgrading? For your question sometimes upgrading may cause some errors. But it depends on your system. Wait some time before upgrading to the newer system. Then may be you can find if there are any bugs. You can boot from older version. My opinion is stay on your current system.
Thanks.!

Comment: That's works well as a general practice. I was interested in some specific information about 11.10 with Rails 3.07, 3.1 and 3.2.